# I want to mount a windows drive into a windows container using docker-compose on Windows

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose

My company stores a lot of important information on a shared drive which is configured as S: (for shared). My application needs to use files in this directory, and unfortunately developers have hard-coded S-drive into the scripts. One day I'd like to change this, but for now I just want it to run.

The software is written in Python, and will run in Windows container on a windows host. I want to manage my process with Docker-Compose.

I'm trying to write a docker-compose file which maps the host's S-drive to the container's S-drive.

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:
  python:
    build:
      target: my_app
      context: .
    image: my_org/my_app:latest
    entrypoint: python.exe -m myapp.main
    volumes:
      - "s:/:s:/"
```

I run it like this:

```
set COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1
docker-compose run python
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: for python  Cannot create container for service python: invalid volume specification: '/s/:s:/:rw'
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project
```

How do I change the volume mount specification so that my host's S-drive is mounted into my container as S-drive?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I had misunderstood what was going on here. The volume mount was failing because S-drive is a network drive and not because it's a drive denoted by a drive-letter.

This is a perfectly acceptable volume spec:

```
"c:/:c:/temp"
```

However this isn't, simply because `s:` isn't a local volume:

```
"s:/:c:/temp"
```

The solution is probably to use Docker's CIFS volume mount driver.

Comment: "the solution is probably" isn't a solution.

Comment: Sorry, you are correct. It is a statement that I had misunderstood the problem.

Comment: I added the comment also because I've been fighting with trying to get shared network drives working properly, including using CIFS, and so far haven't been successful.

Comment: Are you also running Windows containers? Not that it should matter particularly.

Comment: Nope, Linux containers on WSL2. I share a folder full of files to the LAN from a Windows 10 machine, then try mounting that network shared path into a Linux container. Once mounted, that folder is empty inside the container for some reason. I've tried CIFS, SMB, mapping the share to a drive letter, etc., none have gotten the files to show inside the container.